# what cause of Closing session due to exception for StandardWebSocketSession springboot websocket

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-websocket

i build websocket server using spring websocket ,but there is couple case this error is showing

```
o.s.w.s.h.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator||ERROR|Closing session due to exception for StandardWebSocketSession[id=, uri=ws://]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: WebSocketHandler not found for StandardWebSocketSession[id=eb047472-8d50-861a-138e-8c01c9729754, uri=]
        at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.getHandler(PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.java:113)
        at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.handleTransportError(PerConnectionWebSocketHandler.java:91)
```

here is the handler

```
public class PerConnectionWebSocketHandler extends PerConnectionWebSocketHandler {
    
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConnectionWebSocketHandler.class);
    
    private static final AtomicInteger sessionCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    
    public PerConnectionWebSocketHandler(Class<? extends WebSocketHandler> handlerType) {
        super(handlerType);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
        
        logger.info("New connection. Session count: [{}]",sessionCount.incrementAndGet());
        
        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus closeStatus) throws Exception {
        
        logger.info("Close connection. Session count: [{}]",sessionCount.decrementAndGet());
        
        super.afterConnectionClosed(session, closeStatus);
    }
```

anyone know how handle this error ? thank you